# How do I get the median of multiple columns in R with conditions (according to another column)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, median

I'm a beginner in R and I would like to know how to do the following task:

I want to replace the missing values of my dataset by the median for all the columns of my dataset.
However, for each column, I want the median of a certain category (depending on another column).My dataset is as follows

```
structure(list(Country = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola"), class = "factor"), 
    CountryID = 1:5, Continent = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), Adolescent.fertility.rate.... = c(151L, 
    27L, 6L, NA, 146L), Adult.literacy.rate.... = c(28, 98.7, 
    69.9, NA, 67.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

So for each of the columns, I want to replace the missing values by the median of the values in the **specific continent.**

Comment: Hi Ayla and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you post pictures of your data instead of just copying and pasting the text into your question, then anyone who wants to help you would have to sit and type out all your data again. Please help us to help you by editing your question to include the data in text format.

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Help us to help you. Here is how to provide data that others can work with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Also, how would the expected outcome would look like?

Comment: Thank you guys, for the note also. Is it now ok? @AllanCameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::mutate_at` to replace `NA`s in each column (except `Continent` and the non numeric column `Country`) with the median for its `Continent` group

```
df <- structure(list(Country = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Afghanistan",  "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola"), class = "factor"), 
               CountryID = 1:5, Continent = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L),
               Adolescent.fertility.rate.... = c(151L, 27L, 6L, NA, 146L),
               Adult.literacy.rate.... = c(28, 98.7, 69.9, NA, 67.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Continent) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols(), -Country), ~ifelse(is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE), .)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Returns:

> ```
>   # A tibble: 5 x 5
>     Country     CountryID Continent Adolescent.fertility.rate.... Adult.literacy.rate....
>     <fct>           <int>     <int>                         <int>                   <dbl>
>   1 Afghanistan         1         1                           151                    28  
>   2 Albania             2         2                            27                    98.7
>   3 Algeria             3         3                             6                    69.9
>   4 Andorra             4         2                            27                    98.7
>   5 Angola              5         3                           146                    67.4
> ```

Explanation:
First we group the data.frame `df` by `Continent`. Then we mutate all columns *except* the grouping column (and `Country` which is not numeric) the following way: If `is.na` is TRUE, we replace it with the median, and since we are grouped, it's going to be the median for the `Continent` group (if its not `NA` we replace it with itself). Finally we call `ungroup` for good measure to get back a 'normal' [tibble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: How can I save the resulting output? Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: We can assign the expression to a variable i.e. `new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Continent) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols(), -Country), ~ifelse(is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE), .)) %>% 
  ungroup()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the library `dplyr`. I called your dataframe `ww` and renamed your column:

```
library('dplyr')
ww %>% 
  rename(
    lit_rate = Adult.literacy.rate....
  ) %>% 
  group_by(
    Continent
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    lit_rate = replace(
      lit_rate,
      is.na(lit_rate),
      median(lit_rate, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```