# Why does median and coalesce not work with uneven number of rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564823/how-do-i-get-the-median-of-multiple-columns-in-r-with-conditions-according-to-a/60565718#60565718) i tried to give an answer using `dplyr::coalesce` to replace `NA` with a grouped median. But I got an

```
Error: Argument 2 must be an integer vector, not a double vector
```

error. Trying to figure out what was the cause for this I finally got to point where it *looks like* the error appears only if `nrow(df)` is an un-even number? I somewhat doubtful that this is really the explanation but that's the moment I decided to ask the question here: What is the reason for this? The only related issue i found was [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4590) but I'm not sure if this is the same problem?

## Edit:

The error is **not** raised if I replace `median` with `min` or `max`!

MRE:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:7,
                 Group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1),
                 val1 = c(1, NA, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2),
                 val2 = c(2, 2, 2, NA, 1, 3, 2))

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~coalesce(., median(.,na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Raises:

> Error: Argument 2 must be an integer vector, not a double vector

But if I remove the last row (or the three last rows):

```
df[1:6, ] %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~coalesce(., median(.,na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

It works....!!?

P.S.
Using `ifelse(is.na(.)...` instead of coalesce works also independently of the number of rows:

```
df %>%
group_by(Group) %>% 
mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ifelse(is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE), .)) %>% 
ungroup()
```

P.P.S The error is also raised when using `mean` instead of `median`

Comment: Maybe this is relevant from the ```median``` documentation: "The default method returns a length-one object of the same type as x, except when x is logical or integer of even length, when the result will be double."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `median` documentation says

> The default method returns a length-one object of the same type as x,
>   except when x is logical or integer of even length, when the result
>   will be double."

And the error you see is not thrown if df$ID is set to `as.numeric`. Suggests `coalesce` is getting confused by the `df$ID` class.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:7,
  Group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1),
  val1 = c(1, NA, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2),
  val2 = c(2, 2, 2, NA, 1, 3, 2))

# convert ID to numeric
df$ID <- as.numeric(df$ID)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~coalesce(., median(.,na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Notice also how the `class` of ID can vary depending on how it is input:

```
IDa = 1:7
class(IDa)

IDb = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
class(IDb)

IDc = c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L)
class(IDc)
```

Comment: Thank you, xilliam. This explains the weird dependency on number of elements! I really should have read `?median` more carefully! Thank you for helping me out ;)

Comment: I commend your sharp eyes to spot the dependency ;)